# Complex integration of functions having anti derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G$ be a open set in $C$ and $z$ be rectifiable path in $G$ with initial point $a$ and end point $b$. If $f : G \to C$ is continuous with primitive $F$, then the integral of $f$ with the curve $z$ is $F(b)-F(a)$.

I could write the proof if the path is smooth or piecewise smooth. In the book conway smoothness of path is not described in the theorem. Any hint or any link would be appreciated.

Comment: If the path is merely assumed continuous, how did you define the integral? I know there are definitions, but what is the one you're working with

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @peek-a-boo In the book it is proved that the sum converges to a point as the partition is made small given the curve is rectifiable and the function $f$ is continuous. Sorry I'm not familiar with writing questions so not able to format it.

Comment: Approximate your rectifiable path with smooth ones, then prove that the integrals converge.

Comment: @Conifold thank you I understood